# Struct vs test double in ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking

What would the pros and cons be of using an rspec double over a struct?  For example

```
before :each do
  location = double "locatoin"
  location.stub(:id => 1)
end
```

vs

```
before :each do
  location = Struct.new("locatoin", :id)
  location.new.id = 1
end
```

Answer (score 14):

**Test doubles are easier to set up**

```
Slip = Struct.new(:id)
slip = Slip.new(:id => 1)
```

vs.

```
slip = double('slip', :id => 1)
```

**Test doubles generate more informative error messages**

```
require 'spec_helper'

class TooLongError < StandardError; end

class Boat
  def moor(slip)
    slip.moor!(self)
  rescue TooLongError
    false
  end
end

describe Boat do
  let(:boat) { subject }

  context "when slip won't accept boat" do
    it "can't be moored" do
      Slip = Struct.new('Slip')
      slip = Slip.new
      boat.moor(slip).should be_false
    end
  end
end
```

> ```
> Failure/Error: slip.moor!(self)
>  NoMethodError:
>    undefined method `moor!' for #<struct Struct::Slip >
> ```

vs.

```
it "can't be moored" do
  slip = double('slip')
  boat.moor(slip).should be_false
end
```

> ```
> Failure/Error: slip.moor!(self)
>    Double "slip" received unexpected message :moor! with (#<Boat:0x106b90c60>)
> ```

**Test doubles have better support for testing**

```
class Boat
  def moor(slip)
    slip.dont_care
    slip.moor!(self)
  rescue TooLongError
    false
  end
end

it "can't be moored" do
  Slip = Struct.new('Slip')
  slip = Slip.new
  slip.should_receive(:moor!).and_raise(TooLongError)
  boat.moor(slip).should be_false
end
```

> ```
> Failure/Error: slip.dont_care
>  NoMethodError:
>    undefined method `dont_care' for #<struct Struct::Slip >
> ```

vs.

```
it "can't be moored" do
  slip = double('slip').as_null_object
  slip.should_receive(:moor!).and_raise(TooLongError)
  boat.moor(slip).should be_false
end
```

> `0 failures # passed!`

That's a few examples -- I'm sure there are more reasons to prefer test doubles.

Comment: I know this has some years since it was last posted, but is there any chance you wouldn't mind changing the example?  I don't know what moor or slip has to do with boats, and it is making it hard for me to try to figure things out.  If not, thank you anyways!

Comment: If one prefers Structs you can use OpenStruct.new(id: 1) as a one liner to set it up.