# How do you think there are any advantages of using RSpec `double` than `OpenStruct.new`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm wondering if there are any advantages of using `double` instead of just using simple OpenStruct object ?

Comment: Could you provide more detail?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848822/struct-vs-test-double-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

They are similar but the rspec `double` will raise an exception when methods are called on it that are not defined.

```
struct = OpenStruct.new :foo => 'bar'
struct.foo
#=> "bar"
struct.other_method
#=> nil

mock = double :mock, :foo => 'bar'
mock.foo
#=> "bar"
mock.other_method
#=> RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: Double :mock received unexpected message :other_method with (no args)
```